# How can I create a QR Code in byte mode using PHP?

Tags: php, byte, qr-code

I'm using the lib PHP QR CODE ([here](http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/)) but I'm willing to change this. I'm trying to create a QR Code in byte mode. In my application, I need to set 175 bytes in a QR Code, if I use the normal mode I'll have to set something about 234 characters and I want the less version as I can have, so how can I create a QR Code in byte mode using PHP?

Edit:
Or

With this code ([here](https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator/blob/master/php/qrcode.php)), how can I use it?

```
$qrcode = new QR8BitByte(X);
$qrcode.write(Y);
echo $qrcode;
```

What goes on "X" and "Y" and how can I show the generated QR Code?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? if yes then add some of the code here to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator/blob/master/php/qrcode.php

Comment: With this code, I'll write "$qrcode = new QR8BitByte("100111010101");
$qrcode.write(?);
echo $qrcode;"? And what goes on "?"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code sample would really help us diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I just called the method to generate the QR Code, passing the bytes, not characters, and a QR Code in byte mode was created.